# Second input based on what was selected in first input

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have two inputs which correspond with each other on the SAME PAGE and in the SAME FORM.

The input's are:

```
Select Event:
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Birthday" id="Birthday" CHECKED /> <label for="Birthday">Birthday</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Anniversary" id="Anniversary" /> <label for="Anniversary">Anniversary</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Holiday" id="Holiday" /> <label for="Holiday">Holiday</label><br />
```

Now I need to have the input selected above to correspond to the VALUE as well as IMG SRC of the input below...

For example, let's say, if the Birthday radio above was selected then radio below to be:

```
<input type="radio" name="design" value="Birthday_design_1" id="1" CHECKED /> <label for="1"><img src="images/Birthday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="design" value="Birthday_design_2" id="2" /> <label for="1"><img src="images/Birthday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
```

OR IF Anniversary radio above is filled above then radio below would be:

```
<input type="radio" name="design" value="Anniversary_design_1" id="1" CHECKED /> <label for="1"><img src="images/Anniversary_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="design" value="Anniversary_design_2" id="2" /> <label for="1"><img src="images/Anniversary_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
```

OR IF Holiday radio above is filled above then radio below would be:

```
<input type="radio" name="design" value="Holiday_design_1" id="1" CHECKED /> <label for="1"><img src="images/Holiday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
<input type="radio" name="design" value="Holiday_design_2" id="2" /> <label for="1"><img src="images/Holiday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
```

As you may be able to see out, the VALUE of the input changes as well does the IMG SRC of the radio.

Please help, I believe jQUERY will be needed for this.

Thanks,
Chad.

Comment: whatever be your question ..just keep your ids UNIQUE thought out the page

Comment: I know I have to use something like this, but I don't know exactly how to change radio's value depending on what the value of the first radio is. `$('input[type='radio'][name=theme]:checked').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input group_class="group-1" class="event_radio" type="radio" name="type" value="Birthday" id="Birthday" CHECKED /> <label for="Birthday">Birthday</label><br />
<input group_class="group-2" class="event_radio" type="radio" name="type" value="Anniversary" id="Anniversary" /> <label for="Anniversary">Anniversary</label><br />
<input group_class="group-3" class="event_radio" type="radio" name="type" value="Holiday" id="Holiday" /> <label for="Holiday">Holiday</label><br />

<input class="group-1" type="radio" name="design" value="Birthday_design_1" id="1" CHECKED /> <label class="group-1" for="1"><img src="images/Birthday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
<input class="group-1" type="radio" name="design" value="Birthday_design_2" id="2" /> <label class="group-1" for="2"><img src="images/Birthday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>

<input class="group-2" type="radio" name="design" value="Anniversary_design_1" id="3" CHECKED /> <label class="group-2" for="3"><img src="images/Anniversary_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
<input class="group-2" type="radio" name="design" value="Anniversary_design_2" id="4" /> <label class="group-2" for="4"><img src="images/Anniversary_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>

<input class="group-3" type="radio" name="design" value="Holiday_design_1" id="5" CHECKED /> <label class="group-3" for="5"><img src="images/Holiday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
<input class="group-3" type="radio" name="design" value="Holiday_design_2" id="6" /> <label class="group-3" for="6"><img src="images/Holiday_design_1.jpg" border="0" width="150" height="200" /></label>
```

css:

```
.group-1, .group-2, .group-3 { display: none; }
```

and javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.event_radio').click(function () {
        $radio = $(this);

        $('.group-1, .group-2, .group3').fadeOut('fast');

        $('.'+$radio.attr('group_class')).fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: The javascript does not work, it does not change the display: none css attribute or fadeIn the group_class.

Comment: This may be because I also have other radio's in this form.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by last code? PS, my error console is saying: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` on the line starting `$(document)`...

Comment: PS, my error console is saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on the line starting $(document)...

Comment: Add this to <head> tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Boy oh boy am I sometime's oblivious to my surroundings :/ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you haven't mentioned the parent of first three buttons.that would be easier to bind change event without affecting other button on page.You need to write change event for first three radio buttons.then check for the id.and if ids are matched,do the stuff accordingly.

```
$('input:radio').change(
                     function(){
                     if($(this).attr("id")=="Birthday")
                     {
                      //show birthday category buttons
                     }
                     if($(this).attr("id")=="Anniversary")
                     {
                      //show Anniversary category buttons
                     }
                     if($(this).attr("id")=="Holiday")
                      {
                      //show Holiday category buttons
                     }
                     else{
                      //do nothing for other radio buttons....
                      }
                    }
                );
```

Comment: I actually have more than one radio button in the form, I just didn't mention in my first post, so how would I specifically identify that it is the radio from the TYPE radio.